# Show short videos from iOS library

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to show only short videos from iOS Photo Library ?

I want the user to only be able to show and import videos with less than 10 seconds from his Library.

Edit:
I'm using UIImagePickerController to retrieve videos from the Photo Library

Comment: ([Edit] your question, don't post a comment). Your question isn't clear. What exactly do you need help with? You tagged with both UIImagePickerController and PHPhotoLibrary. Which are you using? Which do you need help with? Is your question about selecting, finding, or playing videos?

Answer (score 0):

Using the native UIImagePicker I don't think that is possible.

However what you can do is show all the videos using the UIImagePicker, and if the user choose a long video, push a notification for him that the first 10 seconds will be taken. Would be better if you show him the video and let him pick his 10 seconds from it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is it possible to force the user to crop only 10 seconds from the selected video ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, especially that the UIImagePicker will get the videos as you swipe and not all at once.

Comment: Can I do that using a class other than UIImagePickerController ?